# Saving images on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting the "generic error occurred on GDI++ wen trying to save images.

What I am missing here?

```
string appdatapath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();

if (!Directory.Exists(appdatapath + "/Images")
    Directory.CreateDirectory(appdatapath + "/Images", Directory.GetAccessControl(appdatapath));

if (!Directory.Exists(appdatapath + "/Images/XBLContent/"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(appdatapath + "/Images/XBLContent/", Directory.GetAccessControl(appdatapath));

string imagesdir = Path.Combine(appdatapath, "/Images/XBLContent/");

Image image = FeedUtils.RequestImage(String.Format({0}/{1}/image.jpg", url, c.GUID));

image.Save(imagesdir + c.GUID + "sm.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your IIS worker process has write permissions to the local file system, and in particular the folder whether you are saving the image.

Also, use Server.MapPath() to get the physical location.

See this [blog](http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-exception/) for a solution.

Comment: I am not using IIS yet, the app is still in early dev phase. This error occurs on the VS2010 Development Server.

Comment: Are you sure you've got your paths correct, may need to use Server.MapPath (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714241/gdi-a-generic-error-attempting-to-save-file)

Comment: do you mean Server.MapPath("~/App_Data")

Comment: Nevermind, just discovered on another Stackoverflow question that even I can save there, images will not be rendered for security reasons. I must not put images on App_data. And so my tests saved them correctly but did not rendered them. Thanks, anyway.